# Where to put the Javascript code in JQuery Mobile?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I tried the multipage template in JQuery Mobile but It is not working and also I like to add one functionality which is in second page. That also not happening. Added the source code here.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Admin Home</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="../js/cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../js/jquery.mobile.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../css/jquery.mobile.css" type="text/css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../css/style.css" type="text/css"/>

    <script>
        $("#NewWordPage").live( 'pageinit' , function (event) {
        $("#btnAdd").live( 'click',function(){
            var word=$('.Word').val();
            var explanation=$('.Explanation').val();
            var usage=$('.Usage').val();
            var tags=$('.Tags').val();
            alert("Check");
            if(word != "" && explanation != "" && usage != "" && tags != "")
            {
                        $.ajax({
                            url:"http://sample.in/DailyWord/New_Word.php?Word="+word+"&Explanation="+explanation+"&Usage="+usage+"&Tags="+tags,
                            type:"get",
                            datatype:"html",
                            success: function(response){    
                                    alert(response);
                                }
                            }
                        });
            }
            else
            {
                alert("Please all the mandatory fields...");
            }
        });
    });
        </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div data-role="page" id="MainPage">
        <div data-role="header" id="header">
        <div class="ui-btn-left ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-mini ui-corner-all ui-btn-icon-left ui-icon-home" id="Home" onclick="GoHome();">Home</div>
        <h4>Admin Home</h4>
        <div class="ui-btn-right ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-mini ui-corner-all ui-btn-icon-right ui-icon-gear" id="Options">Options</div>

        </div>
        <div data-role="content">
            <!-- Word Configuration Options -->
        <div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="false" data-theme="b">
        <h4>Word Options</h4>
            <ul data-role="listview">
                <li><a href="#NewWordPage" data-transition="slidedown">New Word</a></li>
                <li><a href="edit_word.html">Edit Word</a></li>
                <li><a href="delete_word.html">Delete Word</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <!-- Admin Options -->
        <div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="false" data-theme="b">
        <h4>Users List</h4>
            <ul data-role="listview">
                <li><a href="users.html">Users</a></li>
                <li><a href="block_user.html">Block User</a></li>
                <li><a href="feedback.html">Feedbacks</a></li>
                <li><a href="admin_request.html">Admin Rights Request</a></li>
                <li><a href="admin_rights.html">Admin Rights to User</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        </div>

        <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" id="footer" ><h4><a href="http://sample.in/Mobile/">Sample</a></h4></div>
    </div>



    <!-- #####################################333 New word Page ################################### -->

    <div data-role="page" id="NewWordPage">
        <div data-role="header" id="header">
        <a href="#MainPage" data-transition="slideup" class="ui-btn-left ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-mini ui-corner-all ui-btn-icon-left ui-icon-home" id="DashBoard">DashBoard</a>
        <h4>New Word</h4>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content">
        <form>
        <fieldset>
        <input type="text" name="Word" class="Word" id="text-basic" value="Word" onfocus="if (this.value == 'Word') this.value = '';" onblur="if (this.value == '') this.value = 'Word';">
        <textarea cols="40" rows="20" name="wordexp" class="Explanation" id="textarea" onfocus="if (this.value == 'Word Explanation') this.value = '';" onblur="if (this.value == '') this.value = 'Word Explanation';">Word Explanation</textarea>
        <textarea cols="40" rows="20" name="worduse" class="Usage" id="textarea" onfocus="if (this.value == 'Word Usage') this.value = '';" onblur="if (this.value == '') this.value = 'Word Usage';">Word Usage </textarea>
        <textarea cols="40" rows="5" name="tags" class="Tags" id="textarea" onfocus="if (this.value == 'Tags') this.value = '';" onblur="if (this.value == '') this.value = 'Tags';">Tags</textarea>
        <input type="button" value="Add Word" name="btnAddWord" id="btnAdd">
        <input type="reset" value="Reset" name="btnClear">
        </fieldset>
        </form>
        </div>
        <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" id="footer" ><h4><a href="http://sample.in/Mobile/">sample</a></h4></div>

    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

The #NewWordPage itself is not redirecting to that page. Please help me.

Comment: As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated : https://api.jquery.com/live/

Comment: your reference library problems..http://i.stack.imgur.com/eydpI.png

Answer (score 0):

It depends of fact do you make single-page or multi-page document. Some recommendations suggest gathering all necessary Javascript code into one file and then call (include) it at beginning of main document before jQm is loaded. Such way of coding make code available to whole document; if you put JS code inside some page then only that page will see code, others not.